# Import .csv file into SQL Server and convert varchar to decimal or money data types

Tags: sql-server, import, data-conversion

I have imported a data set from a `.csv` file into SQL Server using the DTS import wizard. All the data imported is in `VARCHAR` data type in the SQL Server table.

I need the columns containing money values (now in the `varchar` data type columns in the table) to `CONVERT` or `CAST` to money or decimal data types for use in queries with the SUM function. The `CONVERT` and `CAST` functions will not allow a `varchar` to change to a money, integer or decimal.

DTS will not import an integer, decimal or money value from a `.csv` file. So I am stuck with a table that has my money data stored as a `varchar` data type that I cannot cast or convert. I am really perplexed by this.

Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can't you convert? Are you getting an error? I think the best thing is for you to implement the changes you want right in the Import Wizard (You have that option in the import wizard)

Comment: What error are you getting? What version of SQL Server?  `DECLARE @money AS varchar(255) = '18.21'; SELECT @money, cast(@money AS money)` works fine